# File Upload - Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2, image-uploading, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to make File upload image and result is error. The description error the bellow.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

This code controller

```html
public function actionUpload()
        {
           $model = new \app\models\UserPhoto();
           if (\Yii::$app->request->post()) {
            $model->photo = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'photo');
            $model->user_id = \Yii::$app->user->id;
            if ($model->validate()) {
                $saveTo = 'uploads/' . $model->photo->baseName . '.' . $model->photo->extension;
                if ($model->photo->saveAs($saveTo)) {
                    $model->save(false);
                    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success','Success uploaded !');
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);      
        }
```

Comment: You have got `user_id` set as primary key and this must be unique.

Comment: Please consider including the code as actual text in your question, as opposed to a screen shot. It makes it easier for others to read and copy the code from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL server says: you already have another photo in `user_photo` with `user_id` = `1`, and you have configured your `user_photo` table to use `user_id` as PRIMARY KEY which means duplicate `user_id` are disallowed.

Effectively you've built your `user_photo` table in such a way that each user can use at most one photo. To change the photo afterwards use an `UPDATE` instead of an `INSERT`. A few popular databases have an "upsert" syntax which basically does an insert-or-update in one go so if your db supports that, use it.

If you wanted your users to be able to upload more than one photo (judging by the filename) you need to change your `PRIMARY KEY`, presumably you wanted it to be a `FOREIGN KEY` instead to ensure only valid `user_id` may be associated with photos.